# Identity for complex inner product spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a complex inner product space. I want to prove that for any $x,y \in V$, we have the following identities:

$\langle x, y\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}  \|x + e^{it}y\|^2  e^{it}dt$

$\langle x, y\rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \|x + e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}y\|^2 e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N},$ where $N \geq 3.$

I tried to use the polarization identity (and I still thnk is is the way to approach the problem), but I couldn't figure out the trick, so help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, this one solves the integral form. In the "discrete" case, we would get  $∥x+e^\frac{2πk}{N}y∥^2=∥x∥^2 + ∥y∥^2 + 2e^\frac{2πk}{N}<x,y>$ and I cannot see how this would yield the required result.

Comment: This must be a typo (missing $i$ in the exponents). And there's a typo in the first identity ($dx$ instead of $dt$).

Comment: You are right about both, My typo was $dx$ instead of $dt$, and the missing $i$ typo was already in the exercise I got (but I can see how this fixes the exercise and the solution is then straightforward). Also, I can see why this fails for $N=2$. Thanks!

Comment: Just a minor thing: the first identity you wrote should be $||x+e^{it}y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2+e^{-it}\langle x,y\rangle + e^{it}\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$

Comment: Oops, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\|x + e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}y\|^2 e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\|x\|^2+\|e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}y\|^2+\langle x, e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N} y\rangle+\langle e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N} y,x\rangle\right)e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}\\
&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}+\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^{N}\langle x, y\rangle e^\frac{-2\pi ik}{N}e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}+\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^{N}\langle y, x\rangle e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}\\
&=0+\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^{N}\langle x, y\rangle+0\\
&=\langle x, y\rangle
\end{align}
Some observations:

- The sum identity is a generalization of polarization identity in complex Hilbert space ($n=4$).
  $$\langle x,y\rangle ={\frac {1}{4}}\left(\|x+y\|^{2}-\|x-y\|^{2}+i\|x+iy\|^{2}-i\|x-iy\|^{2}\right)$$
- $\{\frac{2\pi k}n:k,1,\dots,N\}$ is a partition of $[0,2\pi]$, so the sum is a Riemann sum of the integral.
  $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \|x + e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}y\|^2 e^\frac{2\pi ik}{N}\longrightarrow\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}  \|x + e^{it}y\|^2  e^{it}dt$$
- The integral is path integral of $\|x+zy\|^2$ on the circle $|z|=1$.
  $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \|x + e^{it}y\|^2  ie^{it}dt=\oint_{|z|=1} \|x + zy\|^2  dz$$